# ggmap and plot shows different zone on map

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

With help of ggmap and plot I want to show the centers of states on the map. The result should be something like this

[image]

I tried this block of code but is doesnt show above map

```
data(state)

cen_df <- as.data.frame(state.center)
library(ggmap)
library(ggplot2)

d <- data.frame(lat = cen_df[2],
                lon = cen_df[1])

US <- get_map("united states", zoom = 12)

p <- ggmap(US)
p + geom_point(data = d, aes(x = lon, y = lat), color = "red", size = 30, alpha = 0.5)

ggplot_build(p)
```

But it shows something lie this:

[image]

Any help?

Comment: Your code is not reproducible. Please use `dput` to share the `state.center`.

Comment: please write `data(state)` at first line to load it.

Answer (score 3):

I modified your code as follows. The `zoom` should be 4. It is also better to use `base_layer` argument to put your `ggplot2` object.

```
data(state)

library(ggmap)
library(ggplot2)

d <- data.frame(lat = state.center$y,
                lon = state.center$x)

US <- get_map("united states", zoom = 4)

p <- ggmap(US, base_layer = ggplot(data = d)) +
  geom_point(aes(x = lon, y = lat), color = "red", size = 2, alpha = 0.5)
p
```

[image]